# Iterate through all columns of table in entity framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working in ASP.Net MVC and using Entity Framework.

I have following table schema

```
MyTable(Y1947, Y1948, Y1949, Y1950,.........Y2012)
```

Columns start from `Y1947` to `Y2012`.

I want to iterate through all of these columns. I am using following code, which is not executable:

```
    EntityFramework ef = new EntityFramework();
    var q = from table in ef.MyTable
            select table;

    int i = 1947;

    foreach(var item in q)
    {
       string str=item["Y" + i].toString();   // Error in Entity Framework
       i++;
    }
```

But Entity Framework restricts to use `item.Y1947` etc, I just want to iterate through all columns. Please help me how to do this.

Comment: what do you wanna do ? Display something for all your table rows, but just for columns starting with "Y" ?

Comment: Decent normalization wouldn't harm either.

Answer (score 4):

In entity framework you dont get a data table you get an object. If you are really wanting a datatable or similar perhaps its best to pick another framework.

However you can do this with reflection, something of the form (haven't compiled this but you get the picture)

```
foreach(var item in q)
{
    foreach(var col in item.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p=>p.Name.StartsWith("Y19") || p.Name.StartsWith("Y20"))
    {
        var thing = col.GetValue(item, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about what you wanna achieve, but if I understood well, I would go for something like that

```
public partial class MyTable {

  public string DisplayYValues() {
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(m => m.Name.StartsWith("Y"));

   foreach (var property in properties) {
      var value = property.GetValue(this, null);
      sb.AppendLine(value == null ? string.Empty : value.ToString());
   }
   return sb.ToString();
  }
}
```

then usage

```
EntityFramework ef=new EntityFramework();
    var q=(from table in ef.MyTable
           select table).ToList();

var result = q.Select(m => m.DisplayYValues());
```